# R AWS - RAM usage

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, ram

I am trying AWS r3.4xlarge instance with RStudio Server Amazon Machine Image ([AMI](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/)).

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        122953       8394     114558          0         13        232
-/+ buffers/cache:       8148     114804
Swap:         1023          0       1023
ubuntu@ip:~$
```

With 122GB RAM and 16vCPU I thought that R would be really fast with medium-sized datasetes. However, R uses only 8.3 GB when I run `rpart()` on dataset with 10M rows and 21 columns ([german data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Statlog+%28German+Credit+Data%29) replicated 1,000 times)

This is reasult of `ulimit -a`:

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 983543
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 983543
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

`rpart` runs now for more than 30 minutes and I wonder why. Is this more CPU intensive task? It does not seem so from htop:
[image]

`rpart()` finished now! Is there a way how to make it faster or this slowness is cannot be avoided when using `rpart`?

Comment: AFAIK rpart doesn't run in parallel, that's why. You can try gbm(), either directly or with caret package. Using caret is helpful in other ways though - if you want to run (repeated) cross-validations or parameter grid searches, then its able to run these in parallel. In essence it's still the same 30 minutes, but you'll be running 16 of them at the time.

Comment: Yes, a really powerful node can't make an application faster if it's not designed to use more than 1 CPU or otherwise capitalise on that specific architecture, sadly.